# I have a regex statement to pull all numbers out of a text file, but it only finds 77 out of the 81 numbers in the file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with a lot of numbers that go to the 16th decimal place.  There are 81 numbers in total.  There are commas and brackets throughout the file, so I (who is new to regular expressions) tried to make one to take out the number.  To put it simply, I need a regular expression that card find numbers that have 1 number(either positive or negative), followed by a decimal, followed by 16 more numbers.  Some examples of the format of the numbers in the text file: -0.12345676890987654 or 0.7564738273839182.  Sorry, but I do not have any examples of numbers that don't match but I can guarantee that all numbers are written the same way as the two examples I just gave.

I have already tried loading it as a string, splitting it at the brackets and comma, but all of these methods are not as elegant and take up way more lines.  This is why I have chosen to learn regex.

```
from re import findall

File = open("Data.txt", 'r')
Data = File.read()
File.close()

Values = findall(r"(-\d\.|\d\.)(\d{16})", Data)


Data = [float(Item[0] + Item[1]) for Item in Values]

for Thing in Data:
    print(Thing)

print(len(Data))
```

From my understanding, my regex statement will find and number, preceded by a "-" or not, followed by a period, that also has 16 numbers after it (ex. -0.12345676890987654 or 0.7564738273839182).  Here is a short snippet of the file I am working with.

```
[[-0.8433461106676767, 0.5111623521263733, -0.39797568745771605,
0.8150308209141626, -0.9157151911545942, -0.4870281951128881],
[0.49680176773207174, -0.18390655568106262...
```

When I print len(Data) I get 77.  I have counted the number of numbers in the file (and did the math as to how many I  put it there) and both came out to be 81.  So 4 numbers are not being found.  A little more information:  These numbers were generated randomly, so there is very little chance that two of them will be identical.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference as the function called is named "findall".  What I am looking for (in order of importance) is:

1. Why didn't this work?
2. What does a regex expression that works for this scenario look like?

Comment: In your question you should include sequences of numbers that match and don't match from you from your file.

Comment: Perhaps, some numbers have only 15 digits or less? Why do you have to matching groups, if you only need one? `r"(-?\d\.\d{16})"`.

Comment: I do not have any but I can guarantee you that all numbers in the file are just like the examples.  They will start with a number or a negative number, then have a decimal, then have 16 more digits after the decimal.  ex:  -0.7584627483617263

Comment: Then you don't have a problem. The regular expression is correct.

Comment: Did you try to display `len(Values)'?

Comment: Couldn't you use parse the text file as JSON and treat it as a list?

Comment: I appreciate all of the suggestions,  but clearly there is a problem as I am only getting 77 out of 81 values, and I would like to use regex to solve this problem.  What I  would really appreciate is an explanation as to why my code does not work and a working solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop to build Data? It actually takes the integer part and the decimal part and sum them togheter. Is that correct?

Comment: There are lots of online regex testers that you can use to see what is not matching. I would guess it is the {16} that is causing the issue see if `(-?\d\.\d+)` gets you all of the matches.

Comment: Looking at the input data, maybe it's enough to call `ast.literal_eval(input_string)` ?

Comment: @All: imho the problem is not the regex, even if is not the best one to match that data. Maybe some ill-formed input in respect to what OP expects.

Comment: @pythonprogrammer: To make a clear statement: You have a file with JSON content, or the representation of a Python list. So, don't use regular expressions, but the appropriate methode, `json.load` or `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex is working as you wrote it, and it is finding a pattern matching:

- a negative sign (optional)
- one digit
- a decimal point (.)
- **exactly** 16 digits after the decimal point.

Given that your numbers are random, some (statistically, around 10%) of them have a last digit `0`, which was not printed, so they only have 15 (or less!) digits.

If the data was generated in Python, there will probably also be some numbers with more than 16 digits after the decimal point, but your pattern will truncate them down to 16 digits.

The solution is probably just to allow any number of digits: `-?\d\.\d+`

Comment: @Jimmy It was clearly an issue with data. Good catch!